# FindGeometricTransform from 3D object external surfaces to a positional point cloud data

Tags: fitting, splines

I am looking for another way to approach this problem. Any suggestion on how to optimize the computing speed is welcome.

I have a `BSplineFunction` which accurately represents the curved surface of a turbine blade.
I have a set of points which represent the real position of the turbine blade surface, we will call it a point could.

I need to find a geometric transformation that would bring the surface into the point cloud.

I took the brute force approach of scattering a large amount of points on the model surface. Then I used `Nearest` and `FindGeometricTransform` functions. Here is the code:

```
F = BsplineFunction[model]; (* Model surface as B spline Function *)
(* Surface Sampling Function *)
SurfaceSampling[p_] := Flatten[Table[F[u, v], {u, 0, 1, p}, {v, 0, 1, p}], 1]; 


ModelSurface = SurfaceSampling[0.005]; (* Actual sampling *)
g = Drop[T1[[2]][[1]].Append[vec, 1], -1] (* T1 Geometric Transform of point "vec" *)

(* CtrlPts is the point could *)
T1 = FindGeometricTransform[Nearest[CtrlPts, ModelSurface], CtrlPts, 
         "Transformation"- > "Rigid", Method -> "FindFit"]; 

(* Apply found transformation to the ModelSurface *)
ModelSurface = Map[g, ModelSurface] 
(* After a couple of iterations, T will become the optimal transformation *)
T = T1[[2]][[1]].T;
```

This is an iterative process, so you can add a `Do` or a `While` loop, which would end when the model does not move anymore. You will find `CtrlPts` and `ModelSurface` at:

[CtrlPts](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0Kk1GOX9aT8RjhIeWh1RGFHQlU/view) and [ModelSurface points](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0Kk1GOX9aT8LTBEVUhPVnV0a2s/view)

I found this brute force method too slow and instead of using a large amount of points, I would like to perform direct orthogonal projection of the point cloud on the model surface. I think using continuous function would be way faster than handling large amount of points.

I was thinking about directly minimising the Euclidian distance from a point to the surface? Is that feasible/doable ? I am open to suggestions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Before posting the solution I found, let me reformulate the problem and give more details about what I am trying to acheive.

A Robotic arm grabs a turbine blade. All the robot positional data is available and the blade geometry as well. I need to find the exact position of the blade relative to the grabber, using positional information provided as a point cloud. The picture below shows the blade External surface as well as the point cloud.

[image: the blade External surface and the positioning point cloud]

The turbine blade external surface are provided as an ordered set of points. These points were exported from another piece software that extract a surface parametrization from a STEP file. The software offers a couple of different type of parametrization, I choose fourth order B-spline and Bilinear. From both parametrization I extracted a map of {u,v} ordered points, defining the surface.

Here is the solution I found

I started with the bilinear interpolation which is the simplest. Here is the sequence of operation I used in Pseudo code/Code. Note two things, this is an iterative process and it has to be started with a reasonably good guess, otherwise it will not converge.

```
Cloud=Import["PositionalData.csv","Data"]*Import Positional data*
CtrlPts=Import["Blade.csv","Data"]*Import Blade Model*

*In a bilinear interpolation, three adjacent points must be contained in a flat surface*    
VertexSurface=Table[Polygon[{CtrlPts[[1+i]][[2+j]],CtrlPts[[1+i]][[1+j]],CtrlPts[[2+i]][[1+j]]}],{i,0,Length[CtrlPts]},{j,0,Length[CtrlPts]}]

*This will create "MeshRegion" from the Graphics3D[...] object*    
Blade=DiscretizeGraphics[Graphics3D[VertexSurface]]

*Compute Euclidian Closest point for each Point in the cloud*
*The output of this function is a point which belongs to the blade surface*
Project=Map[RegionNearest[Blade],Cloud]

*This function will find the optimal point to point geometric transform*
*For some unknown reason, Mathematica could not recognize "FindFit" Method...*   
T = FindGeometricTransform[Cloud, projection, 
       TransformationClass -> "Rigid", Method -> "Linear"];

*Apply the transformation to the set of CtrlPts and iterate*
CtrlPts=Map[T,CtrlPts]
```

Transforming the blade surface into a "region" object is the key, after you can use all the powerful tools related to this type of object within mathematica. here is how I used this function "DiscretizeGraphics" for higher order interpolation.

```
Blade=DiscretizeGraphics[Graphics3D[BSplineSurface[CtrlPts,SplieDegree->4,SplineClosed->False]], MeshQualityGoal -> "Maximal", MaxCellMeasure -> {"Area" -> 0.001}]
```

Comment: I transformed the *.STEP file into a *.STL mesh using FREE CAD software. Since now I can control the mesh resolution, it works even better!